# фон Input-а при автозаполнении формы

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.
У меня input имеет фоновое изображение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при автозаполнении фоновое изображение слетает и получается так [image: 2gf]

как можно заменить фон input при автозаполнении на ту же картинку?

Answer (score 1):

Сама недавно столкнулась с этим вопросом и нашла классное решение:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #000 inset !important;
}
```

Где #000 заменяется на необходимый цвет фона.
Тогда можно в дивы и не оборачивать

Answer (score 0):

ну как всегда отвечаю на свой вопрос сам)
проблема решается довольно легко, не стоит использовать фоновое изображение в input, лучше обвернуть input в div, задать фон этому самому div а само поле ввода сделать прозрачным, а так же на событие автозаполнения сделать прозрачным фон.

```css
.btt2
 {
  width:300px;
  height:45px;
  
  margin-left:170px;
  border: none;
  background: url('https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/black-dark-3d-low-poly-geometric-background_79145-393.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#edd 
{

  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-size:11pt;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;

  width:300px;
  height:45px;
  color:black;
  margin-bottom:12px;

  outline: none;

}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  transition: all 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="btt">
 <input type="text" value="" name="name"  id="edd" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить `autocomplete="off"`, это уберет данные для автозаполнения.